# Create a custom task to cache data to html on demand

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have an external resource (API) that I want to hit and generate some html pages. The procedure is easy to do (fetch data, generate html, save to file). The problem that I am facing is how to script that in order to invoke the procedure on demand. 
I know about pre/postbuild scripts but I don't want to run this thing on every publish

Being a Django dev I was able extend the command line tooling and add custom commands to do this sort of things.

Is there any way to do this? I use gulp. Should I add this functionality there?

Comment: What about using T4 template file? Then you can right click it and do "Run external tool" to run it and regenerate your html file.

Comment: Never heard of this. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Gulp and Visual Studio 2015/2017 then it's easy to do. I assume you already added your Gulp file. Add a new task to it and then just double click the task in the `Task Runner Explorer` tab:

```
gulp.task('mytask',
    function() {

    });
```

[image: Task Runner Explorer]

To show the `Task Runner Explorer` just use the `Quick launch` in the top right corner:

[image: Quick Launch in VS2017]

Of course you will need to install NPM. Gulp needs to be installed locally in the project `package.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp":  "3.9.1"  
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to write that in C#. Basically I already have that in C# and I was hoping to avoid a rewrite to js.

Comment: Then just call the C# exe program from the Gulp task. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec

Comment: You could add the `Command Task Runner` extension to Visual Studio and the be able to run a `.bat` script directly from the `Task Runner Explorer`, but you will have to install the extension. I recommended simple gulp tasks, because you don't need additional tools or extensions, the support is already built-in.